# For a given time and offset; convert to UTC in javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, offset, utc

I'm trying to convert a time of given format "2019-06-17 10:35:18" and offset value "8" to ISO String format "2019-06-07T02:35:18.000Z"

When I try to use new Date() of the format it converts to local time zone "Mon Jun 17 2019 10:35:18 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)". 
But without using new Date() if I use the .toISOString() function, it will throw error.
TypeError: "2019-06-17 10:35:18".toISOString is not a function

Below code is what I've tried

```
function formatDate(date,offset){
  const year = date.getFullYear ();
  const month = date.getMonth () + 1 < 10
    ? `0${date.getMonth () + 1}`
    : date.getMonth () + 1;
  const day = date.getDate () < 10 ? `0${date.getDate ()}` : date.getDate ();
  const hour = date.getHours ().toString ().length === 1
    ? `0${date.getHours ()}`
    : date.getHours ();
  const minutes = date.getMinutes ().toString ().length === 1
    ? `0${date.getMinutes ()}`
    : date.getMinutes ();
  const seconds = date.getSeconds ().toString ().length === 1
    ? `0${date.getSeconds ()}`
    : date.getSeconds ();

  const time = `${year}/${month}/${day}T${hour-offset}:${minutes}:${seconds}.00Z`;
  return time;
}
```

Actual - new Date("2019-06-17 10:35:18").toISOString()
"2019-06-17T14:35:18.000Z"

I Want - for the given time and an offset of "8" and expected result to be "2019-06-17T02:35:18.000Z"

Answer (score 0):

You should simply convert the inputs to the standard format, and then use the `toISOString` function of the `Date` object to convert to UTC.

```
function formatDate(date, offset) {
    // Convert the offset number to ISO format (+/-HH:mm)
    const pad = (n) => ((n < 10 ? '0' : '') + n);
    const sign = offset < 0 ? '-' : '+';
    const offsetHours = pad(Math.abs(offset) | 0);
    const offsetMinutes = pad(Math.abs(offset) * 60 % 60);
    const offsetString = `${sign}${offsetHours}:${offsetMinutes}`;

    // build an ISO local time string with date and offset
    const local = `${date.slice(0,10)}T${date.slice(11)}${offsetString}`;

    // convert to a UTC based string and return
    return new Date(local).toISOString();
}
```

Example usage with your inputs:

```
formatDate('2019-06-17 10:35:18', 8)
//=> "2019-06-17T02:35:18.000Z"
```

Don't forget that time zone offsets can be positive or negative, and are not always in whole hours.